# how to call constructor from main method

Tags: java, constructor, jframe

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Starting");
    }

    MainClass() {
        JFrame w = new JFrame();
        w.setVisible(true);
        w.setSize(640, 480);
    }
}
```

How do I call the constructor from Main method to output a JFrame Window.
Or should I use an entire different class to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
}
```

this...

Comment: This creates UI components outside the EDT thread, which can cause deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very important rule for working with Swing components: *all changes must be made in the event dispatch thread* (EDT). This [includes creating the UI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) components.

So you should do something like this:

```
final class Main {

  public static void main(String... argv) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::setup);
  }

  private static void setup() {
    Main m = new Main();
    /* Do whatever... */
  }

}
```

This makes use of the [`invokeLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) method, which takes a `Runnable`. If you need to pass arguments into your setup, you can use a lambda, or implement the `Runnable` interface with an object that can be configured, rather than a method reference.